# Action in @HTML.ActionLink executing despite response from javascript window

Tags: javascript, c#

The problem I am having is that the method in the HTML.ActionLink is executing despite the response from the javascript window being false.  I have a window asking the user to confirm if he wants to delete an element of page. Upon clicking on Yes, the method in the HTML.ActionLink should be called.  However, even if the user clicks on No, the method is called.  My codes are below:

HTML.ActionLink:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 10px; "> @Html.ActionLink("-Pg", "SupprimerPage", "Section", new { idpageId = @item.Id }, new { Onclick = "ConfirmDeletePage();", @class = "editLink", style = "width:30px" })</div>
```

Javascript window:

```
    function ConfirmDeletePage() {
    var x = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");
    if (x)
        return true;
    else
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
}
```

The method DeletePage is being called each time, no matter if the user has clicked on Yes or No.  Any idea of how to solve this?

The div produced, with id added to a:

```
<a onclick="ConfirmDeletePage();" class="editLink ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
href="/Section/SupprimerPage?pageId=44" style="width:30px" role="button"
aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">-Pg</span></a>
```

Comment: You're returning the value to the click function which returns no value.  This is probably why [event.PreventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) exists.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Yes I added event.PreventDefault() just before return false.  But now even when I click on Yes, the method DeletePage is not called.  I get 404(not found) error.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Actually no, event.preventDefault() does not work.

Comment: But 404 means a round trip to the server? Is is possible that delete page causes this 404 error? What happens when you altogether remove that click handler?

Comment: @OguzOzgul:  I have corrected the 404 error.  However, the method in the actionLink is still being called despite the event.preventDefault().

Comment: @rism:  I am activating the confirm dialog this way:  new { Onclick = "ConfirmerSuppressionPage();", '@'class = "editLink", style = "width:30px" }) in the HTML.ActionLink.

Comment: If you can provide the actual html output of that div I think we will see what the problem is

Comment: @OguzOzgul:  I have added the output a in the question.

Comment: But the script is trying to attach to click event of element with Id "ConfirmerSuppressionPage", not "ConfirmDeletePage". What is the element with Id ConfirmerSuppressionPage?

Comment: @OguzOzgul:  That was a typo error, sorry, I corrected it

Comment: In the generated html I can't find function `ConfirmerSuppressionPage` attached to `onclick` event. In fact there is no `onclick` handler. Can you try `new { onclick = "ConfirmerSuppressionPage();"...` on you ActionLink declaration and check if `onclick` event is generated in the html.

Comment: You have two actions in that case, one with new OnClick and another with jquery. You should have only one. Where is the ConfirmerSuppressionPage() javascript function? If that exists and returns false, you should change it to new { Onclick = "return ConfirmerSuppressionPage();" } otherwise it's return value will have no effect.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to contain the latest version of the code including all the javascript functions etc..

Comment: @OguzOzgul:  Yes sure!  I just editted my post with the latest version of the ActionLink, Javascript and html output.